# Browser check page before dom load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So Im trying to make a page like https://selfbot.cc 5 second "browser check"(https://prnt.sc/psvqsh) page which then redirects to the home page when going to their website using jquery and html. Any idea on how I could do that?

Comment: and who stops you from doing that ?

Comment: Yeah, there are lots of ways to go about doing what you are looking to do. I think it's easier to think about this problem in 3 steps. 

 1. show temporary page
 2. execute desired function
 3. redirect to appropriate page when function is complete.


in your question, I'm not clear what exactly you want to do during step 2 but steps 1 and 3 are only really necessary if step 2 is defined, could you explain that a little more?

Comment: Thank you for your response @SeanClancy I figured it out. The function I wanted to execute in step 2 is verify if the navigator agent is chrome or firefox if yes then proceed to webpage :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the setTimeout function to execute code after a specified number of milliseconds.

You'll find more information on how this function works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

The [`location.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) method replaces the current resource with the one at the provided URL.

Here is an example

```js
setTimeout(function(){ 
location.replace("replaceThisByUrl");
}, 5000);
```

Comment: i hope this is sufficient?

Comment: Yes it is. Even a code-only answer isn't considered 'very low quality', but it's always better to include as much detail as you can!

Comment: I've replaced your link, as w3schools is a very inexact and somewhere incorrect information source... You can refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org) instead.

Comment: I don't think using setTimeout would be a very good solution to this problem, when you need to wait for an operation to finish before performing some action, it's better to use async await, promises, or generators. This way you can guarantee that you are not firing the action too early, or too late.